# MX record for different email domain

Tags: windows, domain-name-system, domain, mx-record

I'd like to create an MX record inside my lan to test a local email server, but with a different domain name.
I have a Windows 2012 DC and a domain called company.local, what I'd like to do is to create and MX record for mycompany.biz and point it to a server named mail.mycompany.biz. Is this doable?

I tried adding it with DNS mmc snap-in but no matter what I try Windows appends my local domain (company.local) to mail.mycomany.biz, so it becomes mail.mycompany.biz.mycomany.local

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a new DNS zone on the DNS server for `mycompany.biz`. Then create the appropriate A and MX record for your test email server.

Comment: Glad to help...

Answer (score 1):

Add an extra dot `.` to the domain pointed: `mail.mycomany.biz.` . This prevents to add the `ORIGIN` to the domain name.

Comment: Didn't work. Windows won't let me add such record - the OK button remains greyed out. Am I doing something wrong?